# ERROR: test_board_topics_view_not_found_status_code - self.model._meta.object_name DoesNotExist: Board matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

i am a beginner in python especially django. I followed the practice at simpleisbetterthancomplex.com. but found a problem while testing.

```
$ python manage.py test
```

and my results

```
System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
...E............
======================================================================
ERROR: test_board_topics_view_not_found_status_code (boards.tests.BoardTopicsTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sysadmin/Documents/belajar_python/Django/mysite/boards/tests.py", line 41, in test_board_topics_view_not_found_status_code
    response = self.client.get(url)
  ....
  ....
  ....

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: Board matching query does not exist.
```

and my code @ https://github.com/githubfans/myfirstdjango/tree/master/mysite

my version

```
$ python manage.py shell              
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 11, 12, u'final', 0)
```

is there anybody who can enlighten me?

Comment: can you upload your test.py ? `test_board_topics_view_not_found_status_code` this one

Comment: my tests.py @ https://github.com/githubfans/myfirstdjango/blob/master/mysite/boards/tests.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your definition of the `board_topics` view. You need to use the same `get_object_or_404` here:

In the first line; you are doing `Board.objects.get(pk=pk)`, which will raise a `ObjectDoesNotExist` error when the pk does not exist, which is the case with `pk=99` in your test. `get_object_or_404` catches this and raises a `Http404` which returns a HttpResponse with the `status_code` of

Change it to:

```
def board_topics(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'topics.html', {'board': board})
```

Here's how `get_object_or_404` looks:

```
def get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Uses get() to return an object, or raises a Http404 exception if the object
    does not exist.

    klass may be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet object. All other passed
    arguments and keyword arguments are used in the get() query.

    Note: Like with get(), an MultipleObjectsReturned will be raised if more than one
    object is found.
    """
    queryset = _get_queryset(klass)
    try:
        return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
    except AttributeError:
        klass__name = klass.__name__ if isinstance(klass, type) else klass.__class__.__name__
        raise ValueError(
            "First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, "
            "or QuerySet, not '%s'." % klass__name
        )
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
```

The important bit is the following:

```
try:
    ...
except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
```